# C# Windows Forms Application - display sql server values in textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I need assistance to display sql server values in a windows forms. In the application below if the query returns a row then the values are displayed. I understand that I am to use sqldatareader but so far I have been unsuccessful how to add it.

```
SqlConnection ChuoDB_Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=test-PC\\tester;Initial Catalog=Chuo;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

    SqlDataAdapter select_adapt;

private void btn_guardian_student_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rd_btn_guardian_student_no.Checked == true)

        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            ChuoDB_Connection.Open();
select_adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Guardian WHERE STUDENT_NO = @student_no", ChuoDB_Connection);

select_adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@student_no", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_bx_guardian_student_search.Text);

            select_adapt.Fill(ds);

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                lbl_guardian_student_search.Text = "No Guardian record exists for this student. Please enter the Guardian Information";
                ChuoDB_Connection.Close();

            }

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lbl_guardian_student_search.Text = "";       

              while (dr.read())
                {
                    txtBox1.Text = rdr.Item["DBFieldName1"].ToString();
                    txtBox2.Text = rdr.Item["DBFieldName2"].ToString();
                }



            }                


        }
    }
```

Comment: This code cannot work. You don't initialize the DataReader. What are you asking? How to use a DataReader instead of a DataAdapter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use a SqlDataReader you need to initialize it using the ExecuteReader method of a SqlCommand. So in your code you could discard all the part relative to the SqlDataAdapter

```
private void btn_guardian_student_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rd_btn_guardian_student_no.Checked == true)
    {
        using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(......))
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Guardian 
                                   WHERE STUDENT_NO = @student_no", cnn))
        {
           cnn.Open();
           cnn.Add("@student_no", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_bx_guardian_student_search.Text);
           using(SqlDataReader rd = new cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               if(!rd.HasRows)
                  lbl_guardian_student_search.Text = "No Guardian record exists for this student. Please enter the Guardian Information";
               else
               {
                  rdr.Read();
                  txtBox1.Text = rdr.Item["DBFieldName1"].ToString();
                  txtBox2.Text = rdr.Item["DBFieldName2"].ToString();
               }
           }                
       }
   }
}
```

Note that I have moved the global connection object inside the code making it a local variable that is initialized inside a using block as well the command and the reader. They are disposable objects and should be disposed when you have finished with them. The Using Statement ensure correct dispose of these objects

Also note that keeping a connection opened all the time of your application is really a big NO-NO in database server applications. You hinder the server ability to serve more requests if you keep your connection constantly open. And there is no great penalty in restoring the server connection because ADO.NET has an infrastructure called [Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) that allows you to restore your connection immediately

Comment: So, what you propose to do? Connection object should be disposed as fast as possible.

Comment: Why do you think so? Shouldn't connection be persistent to minimize query time?

Comment: @Andrii It seems that you haven't heard about [Connection Pooling in NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) and no, if you keep a connection always open you are consuming valuable server resources and hindering the scalability of your server response time. Connection should be opened, used, closed and disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need DataAdapter and DataSet here.
Try just with the DataReader:

```
string _connectionString = "Data Source=test-PC\\tester;Initial Catalog=Chuo;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

string _selectCommand = @"SELECT * FROM Guardian WHERE STUDENT_NO = @student_no";
```

here code for the click handler:

```
 SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@student_no", SqlDbType.Int);
 parameter.Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_bx_guardian_student_search.Text);

    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = _selectCommand;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@student_no", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_bx_guardian_student_search.Text);

                    IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        txtBox1.Text = reader["DBFieldName1"].ToString();
                        txtBox2.Text = reader["DBFieldName2"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbl_guardian_student_search.Text = "No Guardian record exists for this student. Please enter the Guardian Information";
                    }
                }
            }
```